# Init script on multiple <canvas> elements on same page

Tags: jquery, foreach, gradient, repeat

I'm using a jQuery gradient animation script called [Granim](https://sarcadass.github.io/granim.js/examples.html) to produce smooth background gradients, which I've found to look a lot better than CSS gradients.

Currently, when I initialise the script, it only works on the first element on the page, but I want it to work repeatedly across a number of elements on my page.

Is it possible to use Granim on multiple repeated elements within a page?

Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<canvas class="gradient-bg">It works on this one!</canvas>
<canvas class="gradient-bg">Doesn't work on this one</canvas>
<canvas class="gradient-bg">Doesn't work on this one</canvas>
<canvas class="gradient-bg">Doesn't work on this one</canvas>
<canvas class="gradient-bg">Doesn't work on this one</canvas>
```

**JQUERY**

```
// init
var newInstance = new Granim({
    element: '.gradient-bg',
    defaultStateName: 'state-1,
    direction: 'left-right',
    opacity: [1,1,1,1],
    isPausedWhenNotInView: true,
        states : {
            "state-1": {
                gradients: [
                    ['#AA076B', '#61045F'],
                    ['#02AAB0', '#00CDAC']
            ],
            transitionSpeed: 2500
           }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Granim documentation](https://sarcadass.github.io/granim.js/api.html) it states that the `element` property can be a string or a `HTMLCanvasElement`, so you can simply loop over your `.gradient-bg` elements and provide them as a reference to the instantiating call:

```js
$('.gradient-bg'.each(function() {
  var newInstance = new Granim({
    element: this, // note reference here
    defaultStateName: 'state-1',
    direction: 'left-right',
    opacity: [1, 1, 1, 1],
    isPausedWhenNotInView: true,
    states: {
      "state-1": {
        gradients: [
          ['#AA076B', '#61045F'],
          ['#02AAB0', '#00CDAC']
        ],
        transitionSpeed: 2500
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey Rory, brilliant, many thanks. This worked a charm, just made a very small edit to 2 typo's in your code. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you think using a canvas element with this script multiple times on a page would cause significant performance issues?

Comment: Yes, possibly, especially with something as graphically intensive as massive animated backgrounds. This is why CSS is a much better solution - it's hardware accelerated. JS is not.